# Error:(24, 0) Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10]

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, dagger-2, dagger

I try to build a module:api on Android Studio 3, gradle 4.1, Android Studio plugin 3.0.0, using Dagger 2

So my build.gradle is:

```
apply plugin: 'java-library'

repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation project(':api_shared')

    // Guava
    implementation group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '23.0'

    // Dagger 2
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.10'
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
}

sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
```

And I get the following error.

```
Error:(24, 0) Could not find method annotationProcessor() for arguments [com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
<a href="openFile:D:\Users\me\Workspace\Sample3\api\build.gradle">Open File</a>
```

I saw similar errors for guys using old plugin version but here, I don't understand why I get this error.
Any idea?

Comment: @Dipalishah. Ok, thanks a lot

Comment: have you tried using `apt` instead of `annotationProcessor`?

Comment: @Dipalishah. What kind of issue? In my case it seems working well.

Comment: @Natan. Same problem as with `annotationProcessor` => Could not find method apt() for arguments...

Answer (score 2):

You can't use the `annotationProcessor` in `java-library`, you need to use the `apt` but for that you need to add the following to the `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "net.ltgt.gradle:gradle-apt-plugin:0.10"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java-library'
apply plugin: "net.ltgt.apt"
```

After that you can use:

```
apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.10'
```

Answer (score -1):

You need the **Android Gradle plugin** (version 2.2 or newer) to use the `annotationProcessor` DSL.

You are using `apply plugin: 'java-library'` not the Android Plugin.

Comment: I already use version 3.0.0 but according to this [tuto](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Dagger/article.html) I'm able to build it on AS3 without any problem but it uses features not available on dagger 2.10 so I cannot test it to verify if it's a problem causes by dagger2.10 I used before....

Comment: Yes but you need to apply the plugin. apply plugin: 'com.android.application' or com.android.library.